# mei_me unexpected reset

Tags: 13.10, kubuntu, lightdm

Yesterday I experienced some troubles with my ubuntu installation. After reset, my system didn't start lightDM, all I saw was a black screen. I then logged in via `ctrl` + `alt` + `F1` to terminal and saw I'm getting the following error:

```
mei_me 0000:00:03.0: reset: connect/disconnect timeout.
```

I then followed instructions found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184124). That kinda solved my problem, but I'm still getting errors. I had some problems with the mouse jumping around. I then changed my desktop manager to `KDM`. But I'm not sure if this solved the problem or just the reboot.. Anyway it seems to be working now, but i still get some errors, I don't know how to fix. Here are the final few lines of `dmesg`:

```
[  280.812017] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: reset: connect/disconnect timeout.
[  280.812025] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = RESETTING
[  286.824027] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: reset: connect/disconnect timeout.
[  286.824035] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = RESETTING
[  292.836014] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: reset: connect/disconnect timeout.
[  292.836022] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = RESETTING
[  298.848019] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: reset: connect/disconnect timeout.
[  298.848026] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = RESETTING
[  304.860016] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: reset: connect/disconnect timeout.
[  304.860024] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = RESETTING
[  310.872015] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: reset: connect/disconnect timeout.
[  310.872023] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = RESETTING
[  369.179907] show_signal_msg: 99 callbacks suppressed
[  369.179912] chromium-browse[2938]: segfault at 30 ip ad3106d4 sp bfd30160 error 4 in fglrx_dri.so[ac62f000+22d7000]
[  378.472980] chromium-browse[3061]: segfault at 30 ip ad2a86d4 sp bfce8960 error 4 in fglrx_dri.so[ac5c7000+22d7000]
[  381.473299] chromium-browse[3086]: segfault at 30 ip ad3106d4 sp bfee6e50 error 4 in fglrx_dri.so[ac62f000+22d7000]
[  550.590999] perf samples too long (2502 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[  702.692066] init: tty1 main process ended, respawning
```

Does anyone have some idea, what is going on? Any help would be much appreciated! I have ubuntu 13.10 installed, fully updated (I think).

```
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz
GPU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
```

By the way, I have `kubuntu-desktop` package installed.

Comment: Do you need those mei features? I would just blacklist the mei_me module.

Comment: I don't know exactly...its some Intel thingy, I can disable the function in BIOS...but I would rather fix it

Comment: What I know about it is that it is some kind of remote management function used by sysadmins. (It can also be a new attack vector for the PRISM program.) I turned it of on all of my machines which has this feature, because I will never need it.

Comment: Information about the driver involved: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/misc-devices/mei/mei.txt

Comment: "sudo rmmod mei_me mei" unloads the driver and will stop the mei_me messages (from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1196155)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, so after checking what this module does I have decided to just disable it, since I will probably not need it anyway.
The solution was to add `blacklist mei_me` at the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file:

```
# Intel VPRO remote access technology driver
blacklist mei_me
```

Comment: I came here searching to find out what `mei_me` does... it would be nice if you included the information.

Comment: read the comments

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that there is problem with not supported AMT version. I need and use 3.0
At this site https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/509689 told that first supported version is 6. 
After researching i find out that i don't need it and blacklisted it, don't loosing anything important for me.