# what is the use of Recovery Mode in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, boot, recovery-mode

I am getting some problem in my ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop Edition, It is getting hanged on log In screen. If I remove my network cable and restart the system it is coming but again when I connect the LAN cable and use `su` or `sudo`

terminal is getting hanged and nothing is coming what might be the cause of this problem.

So I decided to recover it using the recovery mode(like system restore in windows) I have not created or mounted anything.

will it solve my problem or what the recovery mode do in ubuntu I mean what is the use of recovery mode in Ubuntu.

Comment: Take a look at [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: from recovery mode i did fix dpkg error,update grup it has solved the problem.

Comment: actual problem was this , http://askubuntu.com/questions/419853/mei-me-unexpected-reset  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168403

Answer (score 1):

> If your system fails to boot for whatever reason, it may be useful to boot it into recovery mode. This mode just loads some basic services and drops you into command line mode. You are then logged in as root (the superuser) and can repair your system using command line tools.

For more information as to what you can and can't do from recovery mode, consult the following document:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: Thanks but after logged in as root(the su) how can I repair system using comman line tools means what command should i execute for recovery

Comment: You're already in recovery mode... You can issue commands from there to fix your existing install (edit config files, fix dkpg errors, update grub, run fsck on the drive, etc.) There is no "System Restore" feature built into Ubuntu or its recovery mode. You can't 'restore' your machine to an earlier point.